# How to use select() for waiting ethernet interface state changes?

Tags: c, linux, select, ethernet, network-interface

My program must detect when an ethernet interface turn to `RUNNING` state.

I can poll the running flag by using `ioctl()`:

```
if( ioctl( dummy_fd, SIOCGIFFLAGS, &ifr ) != -1 )
    return ifr.ifr_flags & IFF_RUNNING;
```

But want the information immediately without polling. Currently the program uses `select()` for waiting other events. So it would be nice to use `select()` for detecting state changes of interfaces.

There is a way to do it with `select`, I did read about that from net. But I don't find that page anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the kernel sends information about network interface changes over netlink; see  e.g. here for an example http://softengcrunch.blogspot.cz/2010/12/communicating-with-kernel-via-netlink.html
A quick and dirty hack would be to do the polling after any netlink event (when select wakes up on the netlink socket), without actually parsing the netlink packet ;)